# unable to set minWidth and minHeight to main div

Tags: css, html

I have a `div` under body whose `width:100%` and `height:100%`,

now when i try to set `min-width` and `min-height` to my `mainDiv`, its not appling to `div` tag

Comment: This question is useless without code.

Answer (score 1):

```
.mainDiv{
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
top:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now used to this

```
body, html{
height:100%;
}
```

**than give your**

```
div{
min-height:100%;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn6X2/1/)**